# How can you listen to multiple queues in WSO2 ESB

Tags: jms, wso2, activemq-classic, esb, amqp

I am creating a hosted system where multiple customers can send messages. I am receiving thoses messages on a JMS queue.

Now, all processing is done in a similar way and I want my process to poll all incoming queues for messages and handle them. Is there a way in WSO2 ESB to subscribe to multiple queues?

If not possible, the workaround would be to create a seperate listener process for each queue and have this post the message to a central processing queue. But that seems to be a less clean solution (and I think it will scale worse than listening to multiple queues).

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is making changes on activemq server possible? may be you could create diverts to single queue in [activemq](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/diverts.html).

Answer (score 1):

If changes to activeMQ server is possible ie. if OP is able to influence the configuration to the server, something like ActiveMQ diverts could do the trick.

```
<divert name="prices-divert">
   <address>jms.queue.ABC</address>
   <forwarding-address>jms.queue.theone</forwarding-address>
   <exclusive>true</exclusive>
</divert>

<divert name="prices-divert">
   <address>jms.queue.xyz</address>
   <forwarding-address>jms.queue.theone</forwarding-address>
   <exclusive>true</exclusive>
</divert>
```

Basically, multiple diverts that converge the messages from multiple queues to the single queue. This method has advantage over the reading and writing to single queue-as mentioned by the OP and would in my view scale well as it is inbuilt feature.

Comment: Interesting idea, I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a sequence with all the required logic in it and then call it from multiple proxy services (each listening to a specific queue). Otherwise you can try something similar to [this sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configure+with+Multiple+Brokers).

Comment: Your suggestion is the same as my described workaround... But I would like to not add extra services for each new customer.